# how to create relationship in neo4j based on query request

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, cypher

I need to create a relationship based on query request in Flask. 
Suppose my request query is :

```
http://0.0.0.0:8888/purchased/sbk/24
```

And my request handler in Flask is as below:

```
@app.route('/purchased/<username>/<product_id>', methods=['get'])
def create_cm(username,product_id):
    session = driver.session()
    session.run("MATCH (a:Person),(b:Product)"
               "WHERE a.name= 'username' AND b.id= 'product_id'"
               "CREATE (a)-[:PURCHASED]->(b)")
    session.close()
    return 'OK'
```

I get the return message 'OK' on browser but I am unable to see any relationship in neo4j. Pleas let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Does the query work outside Flask? If it does, you can check what it does in Flask by putting `RETURN count(*)` at the end of the query and see if any relationships were created.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas could you plz tell what you meant by query working outside flask. My code is in Flask only and other things like creating Node works fine. I am just not able to create relationship in neo4j when another web service (as mentioned in query in question) hits my web service.

Comment: when I try to `RETURN count(*)` I get syntax error.

Comment: By "working outside Flask", I meant whether it's working if you just run it on Neo4j, e.g. using the browser UI. Did you put `RETURN count(*)` at the end of the Cypher query? What syntax error did you get?

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas yeah, it was working fine when working in Ne04j. And got this resolved too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal that your `username` & `product_id` in your query are string and not variables ?

Can you try with this code :

```
@app.route('/purchased/<username>/<product_id>', methods=['get'])
def create_cm(username,product_id):
    session = driver.session()
    session.run("MATCH (a:Person),(b:Product) WHERE a.name=$username AND b.id=$product_id CREATE (a)-[:PURCHASED]->(b)", username=username, product_id=product_id)
    session.close()
    return 'OK'
```

Cheers

Comment: @logsima This is working fine. I just changed CREATE to MERGE to avoid  creation of duplicate relationship. Thanks :)

Comment: product_id consists of numbers and characters, so I think it's normal here. Please let me know if i can improve this query in anyway.